# how to load scss module as object?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

According  to [Using SASS#3](https://github.com/leinelissen/laravel-mix-react-css-modules/issues/3#issuecomment-464715549)
By default, Laravel Mix will handle any import for SASS files. This means that anytime you do a import styles from 'blabla.scss', Mix will fetch that object and parse its CSS.

in my case CSS Modules can not operate properly with Laravel Mix (4.1.4)/ React 16.2.0

```
// webpack.mix.js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

let rules = [
    {
        test: /\.ico$/,
        loaders: ['file-loader']
    }
];


mix.react('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .webpackConfig(
        {
            module: {
                rules: rules
            }
        }
    );
mix.browserSync('localhost:8000');
```

I'm trying to import a SCSS module like this:
my React component Progress.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';

import {
    Progress as BsProgress
} from 'reactstrap';

import classes from './../../../sass/Progress.scss';

const Progress = (props) => {
    const { children, slim, className, ...otherProps } = props;
    const progressClass = classNames(className, {
        [classes['slim']]: slim
    });
    

    return (
        <BsProgress className={ progressClass } { ...otherProps }>
            { !slim && children }
        </BsProgress>
    );
};

Progress.propTypes = {
    slim: PropTypes.bool,
    className: PropTypes.string,
    children: PropTypes.node
};

export { Progress };
```

Answer (score -2):

Just try importing a .module.scss

```
import classes from './../../../sass/Progress.module.scss'
```

Comment: still unable to load scss !
when I try to print classes like
 ```console.log(classes) ``` 
I get an empty object!

Comment: Are you using create-react-app? If so wich version ?

Comment: guess you can try and read https://blog.jakoblind.no/css-modules-webpack/

Comment: I tried with lots of  ```loaders, plugins``` using **Webpack config** but without getting a result